# Reaching Rotterdam airport during night hours

Tags: airport-transfer, netherlands, night-transport, rotterdam, rtm

is there a way to reach Rotterdam-Den Hague airport from Rotterdam Centraal? Although in the airport's site there is an answer for morning hours, the bus 33 is not a night line. I intend to travel a Tuesday (3am). Can it be done without a taxi?

Comment: Public transport, no. There's always a bunch of taxis standing outside Rotterdam Centraal even in the middle of the night, but it will most likely be cheaper to order one in advance.

Comment: I really find it outrageous that the only night solution is a taxi. Anyways, thanks for your answer

Comment: Although I agree that it is outrageous, in your case it wouldn't be a bad idea to take the latest bus. After all, arriving at the airport 2.5 hours beforen your flight leaves isn't such a bad idea. Official advise is often 2 hours, and with extra security checks that sometimes occur nowadays...

Comment: Did I write 3am? I meant 7am. 6 hours are quite a lot but probably i will do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked the Rotterdam public transport site and done a search. It did not find any bus on a weekday night.

As public transport does not run at that time on the Thursday, you are very limited.

- A 'normal' taxi.
- A prebooked shared taxi.
- Uber and alike where you contact people to drive you.

I would look into a pre-ordered shared taxi.
But all taxis should be ordered in advance for the middle of the night when it is not the weekend. I learned Uber can not be booked in advance, but if you want to use that service or one like it, check for popularity of it in the nightly hours. (And if not Uber itself, check if you can pre-book.)
In the weekends there will be more transport around, but taxis might not be available unless pre-booked.

I would google -Airport transfer Rotterdam airport-
As I have never used any of them, I can not suggest which one to use. 
What I have seen in a quick search for this answer, as well as in looking for services at other airports, is price differences and differences in the ease to get your ride from the airport. (As in, some services have a service counter at some airports and will keep track on incoming flights.)

Comment: Uber does not really work like that, you can't order in advance (yet). But I once got one in 9 min, in the middle of the night, on a weekday (also around 3 AM, to go to the central station and AMS airport incidentally). And as I was quite concerned about that problem, I checked the app for about an hour before and there was a car 5-10 min away most of the time.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem so. [9292.nl](http://9292.nl) [lists](http://9292.nl/reisadvies/station-rotterdam-centraal/rotterdam_luchthaven-rotterdam-the-hague-airport/vertrek/2016-09-09T0004) the last connection on public transport leaving the station at 0:11, from Rotterdam Centraal.

Comment: A search in Dutch and on the site of the Rotterdam public transport site does not give more options. The night buses only run Friday on Saturday and Saturday on Sunday night.